# how to convert database in text file to json data using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have database data in plans text file like the format below

database.txt:

```
4233            ABAT POULET CHAQUET                                  GH0012                                               BOUCHERIE / CHARCUTERIE                              VOLAILLE ABAT                                        4100       FERME                                                                                                                     4.57   0           1          5.8863  0
384             ABRICOT PASTEU 200G LOU PRUNEL                       LO0009                                               FRUITS / LEGUMES                                     FRUITS SECS ABRICOT                                  2200       FERME                                                                                                                     2.43   20          1          3.8483  0
52              ABRICOT PAYS                                         DN0116                                               FRUITS / LEGUMES                                     FRUITS ABRICOT                                       6112       DANIV                                                                                                                     1.80   5           1          4.5403  0
1979            ABRICOT SEC 250G RAPUNZEL                            64AB250                                              FRUITS / LEGUMES                                     FRUITS SECS ABRICOT                                  2200       RAPUN                                                                                                                     2.28   6           1          3.1090  0
122             ABRICOT SEC TURQUIE VRAC 6KG R                       BY1002                                               FRUITS / LEGUMES                                     FRUITS SECS ABRICOT                                  2200       BIOPA                                                                                                                     5.79   6           1          8.7109  0
```

i need to to convert to json data using nodejs like this format:

```
[
{
  "A1": "4233",
  "A2": "ABAT POULET CHAQUET",
  "A3": "GH0012",
  "A4": "BOUCHERIE / CHARCUTERIE",
  ...
}
]
```

i test this ida It doesn't work

```
var cells = str.split('\n').map(function (el) { return el.split(/\s+/); });
var headings = cells.shift();
var obj = cells.map(function (el) {
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0, l = el.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj[headings[i]] = isNaN(Number(el[i])) ? el[i] : +el[i];
  }
  return obj;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), hence the `json` tag is not correct

Comment: You'll probably want to use CSV parser library, not roll your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mistake in your code was the regex (it was splitting by single or more spaces but you needed it to split by 2 or more spaces)
and in the map function

Here is the correct code

```js
var cells = str.split("\n").map(function (el) {
    return el.split(/\s{2,}/);
});
var obj = cells.map(function (el) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0, l = el.length; i < l; i++) {
        obj["A" + (i + 1)] = el[i];
    }
    return obj;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
```

I would recommend using some tsv parser like (https://www.npmjs.com/package/papaparse) instead of using regex to split columns